# Django: What are the best practices to migrate a project from sqlite to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, data-migration

I need to migrate a complex project from sqlite to PostgreSQL.
A lot of people seems to have problem with foreign keys, data truncature and so on...

- Is there a full automated utility ?
- Do I need to check some data or schema before the migration ?

**Edit** : I tried [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) [DumpScript](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/Dumpscript) but it doesn't run on my 
2GB RAM PC with my current DataSet.

Answer (score 39):

In my experience, dumping & restoring from SQL doesn't work properly.

You should follow this sequence instead:

**1. Dump db contents to json**

```
$ ./manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

**2. Switch the backend in settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    # COMMENT OUT:
    # 'default': dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite:////full/path/to/your/database/file.sqlite'),
    # ADD THIS INSTEAD:
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost:5432/postgres_db_name'),
}
```

**3. Syncdb and migrate the new DB to the same table structure**

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

**4. Load the json to the new db.**

```
$ ./manage.py loaddata dump.json
```

**5. Congrats! Now the new data is in your postgres db.**

Comment: Careful, this is only intended for smaller database sizes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047766. loaddata loads the entire json into RAM it seems

Comment: This causes an error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'dump.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=3): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_76bd3d3b_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (app_label, model)=(auth, group) already exists.

Comment: Regarding my error in last comment it seems that you *need* to apply 'TRUNCATE django_content_type CASCADE;' *before* using loaddata. @Nimo could you update your answer?

Comment: @matandked I had the same issue. I could edit your fix into the answer but I'm not sure about the etiquette of editing when there's not necessarily anything wrong with the answer.

Comment: @matandked `dumpdata --natural-primary --natural-foreign` will avoid you this problem, gonna add it to the answer

Answer (score 24):

The following is a refinement of [Nimo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359683/1839209) and [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477074/1839209) for Django 1.7+:

1. `./manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --natural-foreign > dump.json`
2. Change `DATABASES` in `settings.py` to point to the new (PostgreSQL) db.
3. `./manage.py migrate`
4. `./manage.py loaddata dump.json`

One problem I encountered is that SQLite doesn't seem to actually enforce the maximum length for `CharField`s. In my case, this made the `loaddata` step fail. I was able to find (and delete) model instances with too long `CharField` values via:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["LENGTH(text) > 20"]).delete()
```

Once I did this before step 1. above, everything worked.

Comment: One problem here is migrate writes data (eg default content types). I migrate, then flush, then truncate indexes back to zero, *then* loaddata. It's a lot to remember —and I always forget something— but works well.

Comment: this answer is better than most upvoted, as using `dumpdata > dump.json` does not work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

I've never had to do it but what I would try is.

1. Stop running servers
2. python manage.py dumpdata
3. Alter settings.py to point to the newly created postgres database
4. python manage.py loaddata

Comment: python manage.py dumpdata -> out of memory on my PC...
If I try app by app, it's better but the import doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

According to the @Nimo answer, using from `"syncdb"`, doesn't work in *Django 1.9* and later (that works on *Django 1.7*)

Instead, use the command below:

`python manage.py migrate`

---

And here is Postgres setting configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this may be to use multiple databases.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

It is important you read this section.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#moving-an-object-from-one-database-to-another

From what I understand that means that provided there is no data in your new DB, from fixtures for example you could do

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.using("old-db").all()
for obj in queryset:
    obj.save(using="new-db")
```

Because that should preserve the primary keys I don't think there'd be any foreign key issues.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to run sequel from ruby.
Just run the command:

```
gem install sequel
```

You will need to have installed on your system the devel packages for postgres , sqlite and ruby
Run the command:

```
gem install pg sqlite3
```

Create an empty database on postgresql, let's say testDB and assign a grant permission to a user
From the command prompt run:

```
sequel -C sqlite:///path/to/sqlitedb.db postgres://user:password@host/testDB
```

This will run with no errors.

Change the settings in your django project to work with the postgres database
Run

`./manage migrate (not necessary)`

Run the server

Comment: Made my day, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First things first I'd just try a simple:

```
sqlite3 sqllitedb .dump | psql postgresdb
```

At that point, just test it out. Write some test scripts in Django to output a set of sample records for each application, and then do a diff to ensure they're identical. If they are, then your conversion is probably fine.

## If that doesn't work...

I'd recommend against using Django to dump and load the data, since I'm guessing it's not optimized to do so.

Instead, I'd create a second version of your app with the correct PostgreSQL database settings, run syncdb to create all the tables, then copy the data over from mysqllite to PostgreSQL using some other tool.

The thing is, most of the problems when converting over data is in the table definitions, etc. Those seem to be the most idiosyncratic. If you can generate a SQL script that is a dump of just the table contents, that should be pretty standard SQL `INSERT INTO` commands.

Honestly, I can't see why there would be foreign key problems. Assuming that sqlite is creating accurate foreign keys (and why wouldn't it?) then there's no way that wouldn't copy over correctly. Really, foreign keys aren't special forms of data. It's no more likely that the `UserProfile.user_id` field will contain an incorrect value than the `UserProfile.photo` field would. If the foreign key concern is that the fields themselves aren't correctly identified as foreign key fields (i.e. no constraints), then the option of first creating the database using `syncdb` will address that problem.

As per truncation: as I understand it, PostgreSQL throws a hard error if data is about to be truncated. I don't know if that is the case with sqlite or if it just truncates silently. Either way, again assuming sqlite isn't somehow munging the data on export, the fields should contain data that is the proper length for the field it's going in. The only thing I can think of that might affect this is character encoding, so make sure that the PostgreSQL fields have the same encoding as the sqlite tables do, at least during the import.