# Django loaddata - Out of Memory

Tags: python, django, database-restore

I made a dump of my db using [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model) and it created a 500mb json file

now I am trying to use [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) to restore the db, but seems like Django tries to load the entire file into memory before applying it and i get an out of memory error and the process is killed.

Isn't there a way to bypass this problem?

Comment: What's your django version? Is `setting.DEBUG` set to false?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`loaddata` is generally use for fixtures, i.e. a small number of database objects to get your system started and for tests rather than for large chunks of data. If you're hitting memory limits then you're probably not using it for the right purpose.

If you still have the original database, you should use something more suited to the purpose, like PostgreSQL's `pg_dump` or MySQL's `mysqldump`.

Comment: I didn't know about loaddata was just for fixtures, good to know!

Comment: this way only for cases of database matches. If i want to migrate from sqlite to postgresql - is'nt working!

Answer (score 7):

As Joe pointed out, PostgreSQL's pg_dump or MySQL's mysqldump is more suited in your case.

In case you have lost your original database, there are 2 ways you could try to get your data back:

One: Find another machine, that have more memory and can access to your database. Build your project on that machine, and run the loaddata command on that machine.

I know it sounds silly. But it is the quickest way if your can run django on your laptop and can connect to the db remotely.

Two: Hack the Django source code.

Check the code in django.core.erializers.json.py:

```
def Deserializer(stream_or_string, **options):
    """
    Deserialize a stream or string of JSON data.
    """
    if not isinstance(stream_or_string, (bytes, six.string_types)):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.read()
    if isinstance(stream_or_string, bytes):
        stream_or_string = stream_or_string.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
        for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
            yield obj
    except GeneratorExit:
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        # Map to deserializer error
        six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

The code below is the problem. The `json` module in the stdlib only accepts string, and cant not handle stream lazily. So django load all the content of a json file into the memory.

```
stream_or_string = stream_or_string.read()
objects = json.loads(stream_or_string)
```

You could optimize those code with [py-yajl](https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl). py-yajl creates an alternative to the built in json.loads and json.dumps using yajl.

Comment: Thank you for your help, fortunately the db wasn't gone yet so i ended up with pg_dump!

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my huge amount of time! Respect!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that I was quite successful in a similar use-case with ijson: https://github.com/isagalaev/ijson

In order to get an iterator over the objects in a json file from django dumpdata, I modified the json Deserializer like this (imports elided):

```
Serializer = django.core.serializers.json.Serializer


def Deserializer(stream_or_string, **options):

    if isinstance(stream_or_string, six.string_types):
        stream_or_string = six.BytesIO(stream_or_string.encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        objects = ijson.items(stream_or_string, 'item')
        for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
            yield obj
    except GeneratorExit:
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        # Map to deserializer error
        six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

The problem with using py-yajl as-is is that you still get all the objects in one large array, which uses a lot of memory. This loop only uses as much memory as a single serialized Django object. Also ijson can still use yajl as a backend.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **XML format** for serialization/deserialization. It's implemented internally via file streams and doesn't require a lot of memory in comparison with JSON. Unfortunately, Django JSON Deserialization doesn't use streams

So just try:

```
./manage.py dumpdata file.xml
```

and then

```
./manage.py loaddata file.xml
```

Comment: This worked for me, although in dumpdata you have to specify: --format xml

Comment: I wanted to add one point to my answer - if you use JSONField on your model - you probably cannot serialize it with XML. This is because of default serializer is not able to do that. So you have two options here: optimize JsonSerializer at Django OR teach XMLSerializer handle JSONField

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem migrating data from a Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL, so `sqldump`  and `pg_dump` weren't an option for me. I split my json fixtures into chunks that would fit in memory (about 1M rows for a wide table and 64GB ram).

```
def dump_json(model, batch_len=1000000):
    "Dump database records to a json file in Django fixture format, one file for each batch of 1M records"
    JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
    jser = JSONSerializer()
    for i, partial_qs in enumerate(util.generate_slices(model.objects.all(), batch_len=batch_len)):
        with open(model._meta.app_label + '--' + model._meta.object_name + '--%04d.json' % i, 'w') as fpout:
            jser.serialize(partial_qs, indent=1, stream=fpout)
```

You can then load them with `manage.py loaddata <app_name>--<model_name>*.json`. But in my case I had to first `sed` the files to change the model and app names so they'd load to the right database. I also nulled the pk because I'd changed the pk to be an `AutoField` (best practice for django).

```
sed -e 's/^\ \"pk\"\:\ \".*\"\,/"pk": null,/g' -i *.json
sed -e 's/^\ \"model\"\:\ \"old_app_name\.old_model_name\"\,/\ \"model\"\:\ "new_app_name\.new_model_name\"\,/g' -i *.json
```

You might find [pug](https://github.com/pug/pug/blob/master/pug/nlp/djdb.py) useful. It's a FOSS python package of similarly hacky tools for handling large migration and data mining tasks in django.

Comment: I neglected to provide the `util.generate_slices` function in the answer. It is from the NLP utilities package within [pug](https://github.com/pug/pug/blob/master/pug/nlp/util.py)

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem as well with `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` due to constraints applied on some fields.

In my case I'm running django on aws lambda via zappa, and wanted to migrate to *aurora serverless (postgres)*.  I had the dumpdata file generated from a bastion t2.micro instance, but when I tried loaddata the micro instance didn't have enough memory and the process got `Killed` by the os on loaddata attempt.

So I need to chunk the data so that it can be handled in memory on the instance, and due to the field constraints the records need to be loaded in a certain order.  (*if not I get errors that the linked record doesn't exist*).

So here's my script to *chunk* the dumpdata and chunk it in an order that can be loaded successfully without constraint related errors:

> NOTE: This is prepared on a machine with *enough* memory to hold all the data in memory.  So the results of this script were transferred to the `t2.micro` instance after creation, where the loaddata was run in the resulting order.

```py
import json
from typing import List
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

working_directory = Path.home() / 'migratedb' 
dumpdata_filepath = working_directory / 'db_backup_20190830.json'

def chunk_dumpdata_json(dumpdata_filepath: Path, app_model_order: List):
    file_creation_order = []
    max_chunk_records = 25000    
    with dumpdata_filepath.open('r') as data_in:
        all_data = json.loads(data_in.read())        
        print(f'record count: {len(all_data)}')
        model_records = defaultdict(list)    
        for total_count, record in enumerate(all_data):                        
            app_model_name = record['model']
            assert app_model_name in app_model_order, f'{app_model_name} not in: {app_model_order}'
            model_records[app_model_name].append(record)


        # chunk by model order
        total_record_count = 0
        chunks = defaultdict(list)
        for app_model in app_model_order:            
            for record in model_records[app_model]:                
                record_chunk = total_record_count - (total_record_count % max_chunk_records)            
                chunks[record_chunk].append(record)
                total_record_count += 1

        for chunk, records in chunks.items():            
            chunk_filename = f'dumpdata_v1_chunk{chunk}.json'
            chunk_filepath = working_directory / chunk_filename
            print(chunk_filepath.name)
            file_creation_order.append(chunk_filepath.name)
            with chunk_filepath.open('w', encoding='utf8') as out:
                out.write(json.dumps(records))        
    return file_creation_order

app_model_order = (
    'app.model1',
    'app.model2',    
)                

result_file_creation_order = chunk_dumpdata_json(dumpdata_filepath, app_model_order)
```

Then I took the output of the script below, saved it to `loaddata.sh` and ran it:

```
for item in result_file_creation_order:
    if item:
        print(f'echo "Loading {item} ..."')
        print(f'python manage.py loaddata ~/migrationdata/{item}')
```