# postgresql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "douglas"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate a DB from sqlite to postgresql...so I typed:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

and the output returns `ALTER ROLE`

but when I type `python manage.py migrate` I receive always the same error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication
>   failed for user "douglas"

This is the database sections of my settings.py.

```
# Old, using mysqlite
"""
DATABASES = {
    #'default': {
    #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    #}
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost:5432/postgres_db_name'),
}
"""

# New, using postgres
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'douglas_db',
        'USER': 'douglas',
        'PASSWORD': 'vamointer',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Note: When I run the '*ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD*' I put in the same password defined in the settings.py.

Comment: The error mentions the user account `user` but your alter statement is changing the password of the user `postgres`. Lastly, your settings.py references yet another user; `douglas`. Which user do you actually want to use, and are you running commands that reference just this user?

Comment: Fair enough. What about the SQL query? You should be running `ALTER USER douglas WITH PASSWORD 'vamointer';`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. Did you run the the query I wrote on the postgres database before attempting to run migrations?

Comment: Now this error: "ERROR:  role "douglas" does not exist" =[

Comment: I just try migrate the DB of a Django application from sqlite to postgrsql...I was following this steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476606/django-what-are-the-best-practices-to-migrate-a-project-from-sqlite-to-posgresq

Comment: That's more like it :D I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The SQL you are running does not match the user you are attempting to use.

You will need to [create the user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createrole.html) if it does not exist:

```
CREATE USER douglas WITH PASSWORD 'vamointer';
```

or if it does exist, [change that user's password](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-alterrole.html) instead.

```
ALTER USER douglas WITH PASSWORD 'vamointer';
```

Once you have done that you should have more luck. You may need to [assign permissions to that user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-grant.html) as well.

Comment: where should I put it. I tried this at my postgres container and it errored `CREATE: not found`

Comment: @FarhangAmaji sounds like you might have just tried to paste this the shell... you need to do it in psql.

Answer (score 13):

If you are bone-headed like me and have used 'USERNAME' instead of 'USER' in your Django database configs in settings.py, make sure you change it to 'USER' else you will see this same error. Hope this helps someone like me down the road.

Comment: This solved my problem and it looks like we're the same haha.

Answer (score 10):

Special characters in postgresql are converted to different characters while execution. Make sure you do not have special characters (#,$,etc..) in your password.

If you do, change the postgresql password as follows:

```
sudo -u postgresql psql
postgresql=#ALTER USER yourusername WITH PASSWORD 
'set_new_password_without_special_character';
```

Make sure you do not forget the `;` at the end of postgresql command. 
Then run `python manage.py` and it should work!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'telusko',
        'USER': 'postgres', # not USERNAME, that will cause an error.
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST':'localhost',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to change

```py
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

to

```py
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: That was the old "engine" for postgresql. I kept trying to use that one for some time before I figured out now it was just simply 'postgresql'. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible that your PostgreSQL server is not running. Please run next command, to check if postgres is running:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

If not please run it, using:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Also, you can have wrong port in your settings. To check where Postgres is running use:

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

And after update `PORT` in `DATABASE` config in Django settings

Comment: The missing PORT in setting.py solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was as simple as using capital letters in my db and user name.

It seems that postgres automatically ignores case:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER MyProjectUser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

is then stored as:

```
postgres=# \du+
                                          List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of | Description
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
 myprojectuser |                                                        | {}        |
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}        |
```

So in my database, this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        .
        .
        'USER': 'MyProjectUser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',}}
```

wasn't recognized & threw password auth failure error.

Comment: I had the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why this happens is if you have a conflicting version of postgres running. I had one running in docker and another on my system.

systemctl stop postgresql to stop the system version and purge it if you'd rather use only the docker version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for creating the user for Postgres

```
postgres=# create user username with encrypted password 'password';
```

Add permissions

```
postgres=# grant all on database db_name to username;
```

other useful commands might help

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

```
\du+ #list of user
```

```
\l+ # list of DB
```

Credits to [this article](http://www.dark-hamster.com/application/how-to-solve-error-message-got-an-error-checking-a-consistent-migration-history-performed-for-database-connection-default-in-running-django-application/)

Note: the database name and the username are always in lowercase, even if you create them with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

Wanna do my part as a fellow developer here who got this issue too

You might be following a sometimes dubious "by the book guide" to set up PGSQL with Django. Some of the guides do not require us to write down the `HOST` and `PORT` in the `DATABASES` section. Like this :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'urdb',
    'USER': 'your_username',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':''
}}
```

I fixed this by :

- Check my actual host and port, in my case, the default port is `5433`
- Put `5433` in the `PORT`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'urdb',
    'USER': 'your_username',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'5433'
}}
```

Et voila! No more authentication issues!

Don't expect your environment nor codes to know everything! :)

Answer (score -1):

I had not exactly the same problem cause mine was with `docker-compose`, `django` but mainly with `postgres` in which in steps of building `django` project (note deletion of database wasnt an issue) I couldnt `migrate` my database so by `deleting data\db` folder I attempted to solve it. for more information on my problem [Django Postgres docker-compose connection error mainly failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user foobar ERROR: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248934/django-postgres-docker-compose-connection-error-mainly-failed-fatal-password-a/73259766#73259766)