# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: database, postgresql

Followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. But the password authentication was not working in django on the localhost.

Here is how I am trying to do it 
*settings.py*

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'my_local_db',
    'USER': 'admin',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
}
```

}

Created a database named *my_local_db* with the password *mypassword* and created a user named *admin*. Granted it all the priveleges. But it gave the authentication error.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/postgresql-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)  so altered the user and restarted postgresql service but that didn't work either.

Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060857/postgresql-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-douglas) so updated my *pg_hba.conf* located at */etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf* and restarted the postgresql service.

This is how it looks:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Also tried adding admin as a user but that didn't work either

Update: 
Tried connecting using pgadmin to the database. it gave the same password authentication error.

Comment: This is not just a django issue. More easy if you try to connect from psql and post the error ( without django )

Comment: @danihp Tried connecting to psql using pgadmin. It does not work either.

Comment: yea, more easy to get a solution just asking for postgesql issue not by django issue  ( I guess )