# How Do I get Entries from my old database into new Django project?

Tags: django

SO I have Two django projects Old and New. I Have setup everything in new same to old one. How do I get Entries in database from old to new ? I tried copy pasting the migrations folder and dbsqlite file. Is there another way ?

Comment: Are you using sqllite? or postgresql, mysql?

Comment: I have a db named SQLITE3 file in django directory

Comment: Then copy old project's `.sqlite` file to new one. that's it. Keep setting as it is, if you want to convert to another database like mysql or postgresql. Then I would recommend dump to json and use fixures. OR in same case you can do dump to json file and use fixture in SQLLITE too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476606/django-what-are-the-best-practices-to-migrate-a-project-from-sqlite-to-posgresq This post can help you more.

Comment: Your method did work. But If I Run migrations, my dabase again vanishses.

Comment: May be copy migrations folders with all files.

Comment: You should try to run ```python manage.py dumpdata -o dump.json``` from your old project and then ```python manage.py loaddata dump.json``` from your new project.