# Django SQLite3 to PostgreSQL - duplicate key error on OnetoOne User Model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm having some trouble with migrating from SQLite3 to Postgres on Django.  Essentially I'm following this thread ([Django: What are the best practices to migrate a project from sqlite to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476606/django-what-are-the-best-practices-to-migrate-a-project-from-sqlite-to-postgres)).  There's been a similar error that I've used the TRUNCATE command on and got past, but now I'm hitting a duplicate key error for my own model.

The model client is a OnetoOne relationship with Django's built in user.  It just asks for a few additional details like business type and join date.  And the migration is coming up with an error.  The client, primary key 1 is my superuser with code:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\*******\dump.json': Could not load clauses.Client(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "clauses_client_clientusername_id_******_uniq"
```

Could someone point me the right way?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your fixtures? Also, are you dropping data from the pg db entirely before trying to load fixtures into it? generally with fixtures thats a good practice (for local development only of course, not production!)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can share the fixtures.  Some of the test data has personal information.  As for the dropping data, they are fresh pg databases that I created on pgAdmin 4.  I dropped and recreated them between trials, so they should be fresh each time.

Comment: Can you share a fuzzed up version?

Comment: Sure I can try to blank out some of the info.  Stupid question though, what's the protocol for sharing something like that on stackoverflow?  Is a dropbox link acceptable?

Comment: just marking the json as code with back ticks

Comment: I've just decided to start from scratch.  I wasn't too far along and I could recreate the data pretty quickly with a script.