# How to migrate to Postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

My Django project on Heroku I want to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL. I changed my `settings.py` to PostgreSQL. On Windows I installed PostgreSQL and psycopg2. I created the database manually.

As I run `makemigrations` it creates an SQLite database. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: What are the best practices to migrate a project from sqlite to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476606/django-what-are-the-best-practices-to-migrate-a-project-from-sqlite-to-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

After you have run `python manage.py makemigrations` you need to run `python manage.py migrate` to apply the data to the new database.

Comment: done that ofcourse, but it is creating a sqlite db instead of postgres

Answer (score 0):

@Dacey you'll need to edit the settings.py file and change the database name (and potentially connection).

> Database
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

```
''' here you use triple quotes to block out your original statement
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'old_sqlite.db',
    } } 
close your triple quotes    '''
```

Change the above to something like this

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': 'PostGres_New',
'USER': 'postgres',
'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
'PORT':'5432',
'HOST':'localhost',
    } }
```